How to diagnose flickering lights in house
My house has been experiencing flicking lights and I'm trying to diagnose the cause. The issue is not contained to a singular circuit. Also, there does not seem to be a consistent condition under which the flickering occurs, eg does not seem to be associated to whether any heavy appliances are or aren't being operated (laundry, AC, etc), time of day, weather etc. It seems almost every light is susceptible to it, however I have noticed a few exceptions:

None of our Halo brand canless recessed lights with the external drivers flicker
Bulbs installed in fan fixtures do not flicker (LED LONGSTAR brand E26 120v 60HZ 80mA)
Bulbs in canned recess lights do not flicker (LED Great Value brand E26 120V 60HZ .11A)

Some things I have tried:

Called the utility company which came out and measured no loss of voltage from the utility to the house.
All switches are brand new GE non-dimmable paddle switches. However, I replaced the switch for a troublesome light to no effect
Double checked the connections from the supply to the switch and the switch to fixture.
Ensured all connections in breaker panel (breakers, bus bolts(?)) are tight
Tried different wattage bulbs, dimmable and non-dimmable bulbs, etc

Some interesting notes:
The bulbs currently in our bathroom vanity fixtures (all the same brand fixture) are random box store brand LED 120V 9W 100mA bulbs which experience the flickering. Replacing the bulbs with the following still results in flickering:

.11A Great Value brand bulbs mentioned above
Different Great Value brand LED 10W 120V 140mA bulbs
EarthBulb brand LED 8W 60HZ 88mA dimmable bulbs

However, replacing the bulbs with the LongStar brand bulbs mentioned above ceases the flickering. The only difference I notice is the LongStar brand bulbs are lower mA (80), the other bulbs being upwards of 88mA. The LongStar bulbs are also significantly heavier. I'm unfamiliar with the brand, they came with the house when we purchsed, but perhaps they have better quality components?
Any help is appreciated. Been waiting on a callback from the lone electrician in town for a few days, but would like to address the issue and save the money if it's possibly something simple.
I should note, I experience no loss of functionality or power in any appliance or outlet in the house at a superficial level, however I have not had the voltages measured.

Recent similar question: Why are lights in my home flickering?

What electrical tools do you have? Do you have a voltmeter? Measure the voltage on several different circuits in your home, if you can do it safely. As many as you can. Are they all similar numbers? If you measure during flickering and again when there is no flicker, what are the readings?

I think you found the answer.  Bulbs of a better quality do not flicker.

@jamesbtate I will pick up a multimeter this week and take measurements

@RMDman I had never heard of LongStar brand before and I can't find the brand carried in any stores near me. Should I be looking for something specific when purchasing bulbs that helps indicate better quality components?

Is LongStar the brand?  Or model?  Google suggests that Long Star is the model and Green Watt is the brand (perhaps check if the bulbs say Green Watt somewhere).  Maybe try https://greenwattpower.com/contact/ and see if they can tell you anything.
